# why do not getting notification in ios with firebase_messaging plugin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send notification to the android and Ios device as well.
It's working on android devcice but something fishy with ios token , not getting notification on ios devices , I have enabled background notification for ios. In fact it was working before few days ago but suddenly stopped working on ios device. I have updated [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin but still not getting notification, also visited [firebase_messaging issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7262) ,[this as well](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6290) .

I think there is something wrong with my ios token , because I have tested from [pushtry](https://www.pushtry.com/) website and throw error saying `Please check device token` , but testing with android token , not getting any errors. so I could say that ios token is not generating properly.
I did everything what I could do but every time got disappointed.

Here's my test Code:

```
class PUSHTest extends StatefulWidget {
 const PUSHTest({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _PUSHTestState createState() => _PUSHTestState();
}

class _PUSHTestState extends State<PUSHTest> {
 String token = '';
 var serverKey =
     'AAAAL4uGYoY:.............................';

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   getToken();
   showAlertNotification();
 }

 getToken() async {

   String t = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
   print(
       "FCM TOKEN: $t");
   setState(() {
     token = t;
   });
 }
 

 showAlertNotification() {
   FirebaseMessaging.instance
       .getInitialMessage()
       .then((RemoteMessage message) {
     if (message != null) {
       print("NOTIFICATIONNNNNNNNNN RESPONSE11${message.data}");
     }
   });

   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
     RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
     AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
     AppleNotification ios = message.notification?.apple;
     print("ios ios ios:$ios");
     if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
       if (message != null) {
         print("NOTIFICATIONNNNNNNNNN RESPONSE22${message.data}");
       }
     }
   });

   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
     if (message != null) {
       print("NOTIFICATIONNNNNNNNNN RESPONSE33${message.data}");
     }
   });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () => sendNotification(),
         child: Text("SEND NOTIFICATION"),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }


// My FCM Payload To send notification to the device:

 sendNotification() async {
   print("send notification button pressed");
   try {
     http.Response response = await http.post(
       Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
       headers: <String, String>{
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
       },
       body: jsonEncode(
         <String, dynamic>{
           'notification': <String, dynamic>{
             'body': 'this is a body',
             'title': 'this is a title',
             "content_available": true 
           },
           'priority': 'high',
           'data': <String, dynamic>{
             'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
             'id': '1',
             'status': 'done'
           },
           'to': token,
         },
       ),
     );
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       print("SENT NOTIFICATION TO THE DEVICE :$token");
       Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SENT NOTIFICATION TO THE DEVICE :$token");
     } else {
       print("error push notification");
       Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "error push notification");
     }
   } catch (e) {
     print("error push notification");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: make user you have allow for notification permission.

Comment: Did you add your APN certificate in firebase console? Also it doesn't work on iOS simulators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I found my stupidity, what I exactly did. actually It was 2 major mistakes.

- firstly, I used [permission_hander](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) and haven't ask for permission for the notification because I was thinking it will be auto ask , when I added remote notification to the `plist`file.
- secondly, My huge stupidity, I have created 2 firebase project , added configuration file for android (`google-service.json`) from the another and ios(`google-service.plist`) from the other projects. and added `server-key` to the backend from one of them. Nothing wrong with FCM token.

that's why it were working for android only.

Now I have recognised my silliness and deleted duplicate firebase project one, and added configuration file from the original one and updated my `server-key` to my backend. and also asking permission for notification using `permission_handler`. That's all.